# Stored procedure returned results crossed between calls

Tags: sql-server, aws-lambda

I have a stored procedure that creates an invoice. An `itemID`, `customerID` and `orderID` are passed in. The procedure saves the passed values to a table and continues.

Inserts into the invoice and a couple other tables and updates the items table. The return from this procedure is a select based on the `invoiceID` created by the insert, saved to `@invoiceID` using `scope_identity()`:

```
declare @invoiceID int

insert into invoice(custID, orderID)
select @custID, @orderID

select @invoice_id = scope_identity()
```

Return value:

```
select *
from items a
join invoice b on a.invoice_id = b.invoice_id
where b.invoice_id = @invoiceID
```

Here's where this gets fun. The following comes from AWS using PYODBC, lambdas, with the results saved to separate logs. Two calls were made at the same time (logged on AWS side 2 seconds apart). Should be completely separate processes, however:

- Call 1 passes item 1, custID 1 and orderID 1. No result is returned to AWS per AWS log however; call is in the log table, invoice exists for this orderID / custID.
- Call 2 passes item 2, custID 2 and orderID 2. Result returned is item 1 sold to custID 1 for orderID 1. Nothing in the log table for item 2, no invoice created for custID 2 or orderID 2

Why did call 1 get nothing back, and call 2 got call 1's invoice?

Comment: We would need to see your calling / results processing code.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't oversimplified the problem? `scope_identity()` will return the last generated id within the current session... so returning the wrong value with the code shown seems pretty unlikely. And 2 seconds apart is forever in database terms - so its not going to be a timing issue. Are there any triggers? Any try/catch blocks any possibility that a particular insert fails?

Comment: Please show your Lambda function's code.

Comment: I can see this happening due to an asynchronous DB call, storing the result in a global variable, and Lambda container reuse. Which is why including your code in your question is important.

Comment: Were you using `nolock` or `read uncomitted`?